# XMLHttpRequest being blocked by CORS Policy : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Trying to use a proxy

Tags: node.js, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to obtain an access token to access the Graph API from Microsoft in a SharePoint Add-ins. When loading a page from the add-ins, a js script execute to obtain the access token. However, when trying to obtain a token, I get this error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/(TenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=(hidden)&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44368%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+offline_access+files.read+user.read' (redirected from 'http://localhost:44368/') from origin 'https://mysite-.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am a bit lost, and my comprehension is not good enough to understand what's going on.

This is the code executed in my App.js who calls my server:
`function Authenticate() { $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:44368", // Use your proxy route method: "GET", dataType: "json", success: function (data) { console.log("Received data from the proxy:", data); // Handle the data as needed }, error: function (xhr, status, error) { console.error("Proxy request error:", status, error); // Handle errors here } }); }`

And this is the code from the node.js server:

```
`const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const app = express();
const port = 44368;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const allowedOrigins = ['(hidden)'];
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    return next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // Redirect to the Azure AD authorization endpoint to start the OAuth flow
    const authParams = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "openid profile offline_access files.read user.read",
        // Add any additional parameters as needed
    });

    const authUrl = `${authorizationUrl}?${authParams}`;
    res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code;

    if (!code) {
        return res.status(400).send("Authorization code not found in the callback.");
    }

    try {
        // Exchange the authorization code for an access token
        const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: "openid profile offline_access",
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            client_secret: clientSecret,
        }));

        const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
        const refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;


        // Redirect the user to a success page or your app's main page
        if (!accessToken) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Access token not found in the query parameters." });
        }

        res.json({ accessToken });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during token exchange:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error during token exchange.");
    }
});`
```